# Embedding PHP in jplayer

Tags: php, audio, jplayer

I am pulling mp3 file locations from my mysql database using PHP and would like to pass those variables to a script in my page.

I want to know how to have the below file name echo from an array in my database:

```
var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
{
    m4a:   "downloads/uploads/p170f0vflo1066jbc1l4pp38st01.mp3",
}, {
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
    swfPath: "js",
    wmode: "window"
});
```

So I would need something like this:

```
var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
{
    m4a: "<?php echo $music_p; ?>",  <---This is what I need (from a database)
}, {
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
    swfPath: "js",
    wmode: "window"
});
```

Comment: As long as $music_p is defined in the same file that javascript is executed, your code will work. If the JavaScript is in a separate file and is script src'd in, you'll have to do some reworking.

Comment: What is the question here, what is your coding problem?

Comment: Hey @JimmyBanks its a pretty straight forward question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sean Johnson said it should work if you define $music_p in the same file as the javascript is. For instance in the javascript tags

```
<?php $music_p = array("downloads/uploads/p170f0vflo1066jbc1l4pp38st01.mp3") ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
//JavaScript code (define functions here)
var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
{
m4a: "<?php echo $music_p[0]; ?>",  <----------This is what i want!
}, {
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
    swfPath: "js",
    wmode: "window"
});
</script>
```

I believe this is what you might want to look at.

Comment: what about if i want to display it from my sql in rows IE: mysql_select_db("songs_list", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM songs");

echo "<table border='.5' color='#fff'>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

Comment: I can't check now but ill have alook for you when I get home
If you define, technically, a variable in the same file or include it into the same file as the script that uses it, it will/should work.